# how to screen mirror in flutter , how to record our screen and send live video ? flutter app and flutter web

Tags: android, flutter

how to screen mirror in Flutter, how to record our screen and send a live video? flutter app and Flutter web [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyM14.jpg)